# Off-chain database and access control management by smart contracts

Tags: oracles, access

I am thinking about an application which consists of two main components; off-chain database and ethereum blockchain for managing the accesses to the off-chain database. Is there any similar sample? 
The main challenge for me is connecting the off-chain database to smart contracts. I am not sure using oraclize is an appropriate solution for this application. Do I need to write my own framework to forward requests from off-chain database to smart contracts? If yes can you help me how should I start?

I would be appreciated if you introduce some helpful sources.

Answer (score 1):

Search Google for the words "DAPP," "Distributed Application," "Solidity," "Web3.0," "Truffle," "RPC," "EVM," "MyEtherWallet," "Metamask," "Infura," and read, read, read. These are sort of the basics.

If you have a moderately good understanding of each of these things, you'll be on your way. I ordered the words in the way you might come to understand the issues. Perhaps others will add to or expand the list.

"Forwarding requests from off-chain database to smart contracts" is basically a DAPP.

**Edit by Original Answerer A Year Later:**

Knowing what I know now, I think I should have called this "using an oracle".